# Any new stuff in libpng 1.4 series?

Tags: c++, c, libpng

What is new in the soon to be released libpng 1.4 series? The DLL is almost twice the size of 1.2.41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The many changes are listed [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/02-libpng-devel/1.4.0rc02/libpng-1.4.0rc02-README.txt/download), starting with the line `version 1.4.0beta1 [April 20, 2006]`

Comment: link is now https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng14/older-releases/1.4.0/libpng-1.4.0-README.txt/download

Answer (score 2):

Release notes are here:

http://cdnetworks-us-1.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/02-libpng-devel/1.4.0rc02/libpng-1.4.0rc02-README.txt